# SQLite create table on trigger

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a new table for every row that is inserted into an existing table.

As I understand only DML operation is allowed on trigger, is it correct.
If so is there a alternative way of achieving my objective?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite indeed allows only DML in a trigger body.

However, you could do a SELECT with a [user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that then executes another SQL command to create the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
...
BEGIN
    SELECT my_create_table_function(NEW.name);
END;
```